# User experience after asking a question

Tags: feature-request

One problem I have seen of stackoverflow is: if once someone answers a question I ask, it seems like I stop getting any more views or answers. My guess is that this happens because no one wants to answer a question that's already been answered (even if the first answer was wrong).

One idea to overcome this would be to add the functionality to mark answers as incorrect and then on the question listing page maybe change the text to "0 **correct** answers" instead of "1 answer" ("1 answer" that does nothing except prevent future traffic to the question).

This is however, just an idea - one potential work around - probably not the best one either.

Comment: not exactly sure what you're getting at here

Comment: The closest thing is downvoting, and/or a polite comment explaining that the answer didn't solve your problem.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40527/add-the-ability-to-mark-an-answer-as-incorrect

Comment: This is not simply requesting to mark answers as incorrect. This is a multipart stategy to keep traffic going to questions that are answered incorrectly.

Comment: you could always apply a bounty to it if you feel you need more visits. I wouldn't be worried about the drop in traffic, i would assume a lot of the traffic that you lose in this case are just FGITW users anyway.

Comment: Speaking only for myself, I'll only be less likely to go to a question if it has an `ACCEPTED` answer, and that's only if the question doesn't strongly interest me.  Given the quality of many answers, I'm not turned off by 1 or many unaccepted answers.

Comment: Also, note that an answer being posted actually bumps the question to the top in the front page view, and others.

Comment: This is already being addressed by the system, in a way: questions leave the "unanswered" tab only when they have an answer with at least one upvote.

Comment: The same as Michael above, if a question is *accepted*, I'm less likely to look at it when looking for stuff to answer. Having answers doesn't stop me from looking further into an interesting question title/excerpt. And if it is *really interesting*, having an accepted answer won't stop me from posting an alternative, if I have one.

Answer (score 11):

No. The asker already has the power to mark an answer as accepted. That's a special privilege that askers have. That's *enough privilege* in the hands of the asker.

What you are requesting implies that an asker dissatisfied with the answers could go to each answer an mark them as "incorrect" so the the count of *correct answers* remains "0". Given that the OP is sometimes wrong about correctness, that's a privilege that they should not possess. Their opinion of correctness should not be elevated above the opinion of others. (In fact, very often the OP is not particularly well placed to evaluate correctness, seeing as they have the need to ask in the first place.) It is enough privilege that they have the acceptance mark. For the rest, they can upvote or downvote answers like everyone else. That askers can put an acceptance mark is already controversial, because sometimes they accept bad answers, and some users confuse the acceptance mark with a "this is the best answer" mark, or a "this is correct" mark when it only means that it is the answer the asker found most helpful.

That people will not be as inclined to look at a question because it has answers (or an accepted answer) is indeed deplorable, but the solution is not what you propose.

Comment: Considering that the user does indeed have the responsibility to mark an answer as correct, the user is implicitly marking other answers as incorrect anyway.

Comment: "Mark a *question* as correct"? Do you mean mark an *answer*? If so, then you seem to think the acceptance mark is a correctness mark but as I said in my answer **it is not an correctness mark**. If you think it is, then you are misunderstanding what it means.

Comment: If I'm wrong for thinking that a green tick is a correctness mark then I'm most likely wrong with 99% of all other users.

Comment: That fact that many people have a wrong notion does not make that notion right.

Comment: @ThreaT just as Louis wrote - `it is the answer the asker found most helpful`, not necessary the best, the only one correct , nor the most complete.

Comment: Still, on the listing page, the user sees "5 answers" not "5 awful answers" and simply doesn't bother adding to the unanswered monstrosity.

Comment: @ThreaT Yes, you get less attention from possible answerers if there are already answers. That's unfortunate, but somewhat understandable. Look at it from the other side: If you answer a question that already has answers, particularly if they are upvoted/accepted, you have little chance of your answer even getting noticed. So if somebody cares about their answers being upvoted/accepted, they're probably better off looking elsewhere. The real problem IMHO is OPs often accepting answers too quickly, and never even looking at more answers once they got one.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Thank you for the above. I think that it's true what you say and I agree with a lot of it. Going forward, perhaps marking an answer as incorrect is somewhat motivation for other answerers to answer regardless of the other answers?

Comment: Note also that the unanswered tab http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered contains questions that have no up voted answers (clearly shown on meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered ).  This is one of the reasons that up voting answers that don't work can take away from the visibility of the question.

Comment: @ThreaT I guess I'm finally part of the 1% :D On a sidenote, the tooltip for the mark flag says *Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution*. There's nothing there about the answer being correct or not.

Answer (score 5):

When there is an accepted answer on the questions page there *is* a visual change.  On SO the number of answers is yellow instead of white.  On other sites the visual distinction is different.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not talking about an acceptance change, I'm talking about a mere answer. There is definitely a change in traffic after that event occurs.

Comment: @ThreaT Your proposal is to distinguish "correct" answers from answers that haven't been marked as correct.  That is already done.

Comment: Not only but to also hide the fact that there's an answer in a way that doesn't make the user lose anything.

Comment: @ThreaT But there is an answer, and others may wish to evaluate it.

Comment: Then go to the page. Currently, that will just prevent more page visits.